# Eclipse save before build

Tags: android, eclipse-3.6

I have checked the Pref -> General -> Save auto before build box. But it still asks me each time when i click run.  just want the save popup to go away.

I am editing the main.xml resource file...

Comment: which version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: helios is what i am working with :-)

Comment: still no luck on this one...    should i re-download helios ?

Answer (score 1):

Try closing and open again.  Sometimes Eclipse doesn't refresh its environment properly.

Comment: 'main.xml'has been modified.  Save changes?

Comment: Same problem here on Windows. But works fine on Linux.